# R - aggregate factor/character variable

Tags: r, character, aggregate, r-factor

I have this kind of data frame :

```
df<- data.frame(cluster=c('1','1','2','3','3','3'), class=c('A','B','C','B','B','C'))
```

I would like to get for each cluster (1,2,3), the class which appears the most often. In case of a tie, it would also be great to get an info, as for example the combination of the classes (or if not possible just have NA).
So for my example, I would like to have something like this as result:

```
 cluster  class.max
   1        'A B' (or NA)
   2         'C'
   3         'B'
```

Maybe I should use `aggregate()`  but don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rank` has ways of dealing with ties:

```
aggregate(class~cluster,df,function(x) paste(names(table(x)[rank(-1*table(x),ties.method="min")==1]),collapse=" "))
  cluster class
1       1   A B
2       2     C
3       3     B
```